# How to implement a hierarchical lock or other synchronization pattern?

Tags: .net, multithreading, caching, atomic

I have a series of logically connected collections of A, B and C objects, that are accessed by writer threads, reading-only threads and read-write threads.

Every A object can have several related B objects, and every B object can have several related C objects. One B object can be related to only one A object, and similarly, one C object can be related to only one B and A object. This means that when updating A, all related Bs and Cs must also be locked, and in reverse, if updating a C, the corresponding B and A are also locked?

How can i achieve the synchronization of such a structure?

Comment: Why all they have to be locked? Do they share any information between each other? If they don't then no need for locking all. If they do, design is not optimised.

Comment: @Aliostad They do not share state, but from a business point of view they need to be accessed together (for reading), but can be updated individually. If this design (a hierarchical structure) is not optimized, what would be a good design?

Answer (score 0):

> when updating A, all related Bs and
>   Cs must also be locked, and in
>   reverse, if updating a C, the
>   corresponding B and A are also locked

With this restriction in place you only need one mutex for each set of an A and its associated Bs and Cs. This mutex logically belongs in the A object, since there is only one of these the group, but it is probably wise to keep a reference in the B and C objects, so that it can be locked directly from there when an update must be made, without having to first traverse the object tree to find the mutex.